# Difference between aggregation and dependency injection

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection, aggregation

I have recently studied dependency injection design pattern .

```
class User
{

private $db;

public function __construct(Database $db) 
{
        $this->$db = $db;
}

}
```

I can not help but wonder that is the **same** thing that i learned in **aggregation**. Please do correct me if I am wrong . I know ***goals*** of **dependency injection** and **aggregation** are **different** . Is there anything that I am missing ?

Comment: You have 3 good answers to your question. Please post comments on any of these answers for further clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aggregation is a form of object composition. It has nothing to do with *dependency injection*.

In the other hand, *dependency injection* isn't about how objects are associated with but how to get other objects (dependencies) into a particular object. *Dependencies* could be aggregates, services, repositories, validators, literals...

Usually, in strongly-typed languages, *dependencies* are introduced as interfaces to avoid coupling your objects to implementation details. In the opposite side, in dynamically-typed languages, conventions and a strong documentation do the trick to build up a good and tightly-coupled dependency graph.

Note that a database couldn't be an aggregate. Not all associations are considered to be *aggregation*, while you could consider an *injected dependency*.

Anyway, there's some design smell in your reasoning: an user shouldn't depend on a database, but a data layer / data mapping layer would be a better candidate to be injected into your user entity if you're going to implement something like [active record pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern).

Answer (score 5):

> I can not help but wonder that is the same thing that i learned in aggregation

Consider a `Department` class for example that has an array of `Professor` objects as an instance variable. There are two ways in which you can initialize the professor array with some `Professor` objects.

1. You could initialize the elements of the `Professor` array within the `Department` class in some method that takes no parameters by saying `professors[0]=new Professor("CK");` and `professors[1]=new Professor("MK");`.
2. You could provide a constructor that takes an array of `Professor` type as its argument. Any class that wants to instantiate a `Department` would then have to also pass an array of `Professor` objects to the constructor.

**Aggregation :** It doesn't matter whether you use option 1 or 2 to define how a `Department` gets its professors. A professor will continue to exist even if there is no department (assuming the professor belongs to more than one department) and this is therefore said to be aggregation regardless of how the department gets its professors.

**Dependency Injection** If you use option 2 to create a `Department` instance, this will be termed as dependency injection. A department needs professors and you are fulfilling this dependency by providing it from outside the `Department` class.

In other words, *Aggregation* is a type of relationship that can be modeled either using option 1 or option 2 (or other options such as getting the professors from a database and filling the `Professor` array in `Department` inside a method). Dependency injection is way of designing your class so that its dependencies can be provided from outside the class. An aggregate relationship can be modeled to support dependency injection but that does not mean *Aggregation* and *Dependency Injection* are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation is generally modeled as a one-to-many relationship, and furthermore, tends to imply part-whole semantics. For these reasons, a DB of Users would generally *not* be considered aggregation: the relationship is 1:1 and the concept of a User does not necessarily imply a DB.

Contrast this with the common aggregation example of a car and its wheels. There is a one-to-many relationship, and the concept of a Car usually implies that it has wheels.

Dependency Injection may be thought of as the way in which a relationship is created. The relationship may be 1:1 or one-to-many. It may imply certain semantics, or not. The critical feature of DI is that `User` does not control the creation of `DB`, nor initiate its creation.

In practice, aggregation relationships may often be created via dependency injection; but that does not imply the two concepts are equivalent. DI can create other kinds of relationships, and aggregation may be created without DI.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation is a way of maintaining associations between objects. You use this term when describing how you **structure relations** between objects. It is a domain term, the same kind of relation exists between objects in real life.

Dependency injection is a way to **manage dependencies** between objects in order to achieve loose coupling. The same techniques can be used in aggregates. But usually, in aggregates, it is not about coupling but about how your objects are related. This term also has analogies from real life but they are used mostly to explain what is the inversion of control, usually, there is no correspondence to your domain.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to add these points.

If I think from your point of view you should be asking this question because **Aggregation** & **Dependency Injection** promotes an entity which can be put into some other entities and also can work alone.

But there is a difference. In ***Aggregation*** you are working with direct objects. i.e. objects which maintains a state, life-cycle etc.

Ex:
**Bulb & Room**

- Instances of **Bulb** can be put into instances of **Room**.
- But not only **Room**, some instances can be put into instances of **Car**, **Radio** etc.
- And also instances of **Bulb** can work independently without being put into the instances of other objects too.

But in ***Dependency Injection*** we focus on class level interactions. This is somewhat diverged with pure OOP practice. Actually in DI we tend to inject ***stateless classes*** (worker classes) into some other classes. Though they look like objects they are actually just stateless classes that are being injected. And instances of that class can stand independently too. DI is widely used as an alternative for **[Traditional Singleton Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton)** because that traditional way has some negative side-effects.

Ex:

Assume a stateless worker class called **StringUtils** (not the apache one which is stacked with static methods.). It can be injected into classes called **NounUtils**, **VerbUtils** etc. And also instances of **StringUtils** can also exist.

Hope you got an idea. :))